# How to get holiday names from moment-holidays.js?

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I have 2 moments: `moment_start_date` and `moment_end_date`.
I can figure out all holidays between those 2 moments using:

```
var holidays = moment_start_date.holidaysBetween(moment_end_date);
```

This gives me an array of moment objects, which tells me what days the holidays fall on, but it doesn't actually tell me the names of those holidays.

How do I go from a moment to a holiday name?
Most of the documentation for moment-holidays.js appears to go from a holiday name, to a date (the other direction).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We get the name of the holiday (if there is one) with the `.isHoliday()` method.

example: https://repl.it/@AndreasTeneketz/momentHoliday

```
const moment=require('moment-holiday')

const start = moment('01.01.2000','DD.MM.YYYY')
const end = moment('01.05.2000','DD.MM.YYYY')

const momentList = start.holidaysBetween(end)

const holidayList = momentList.map(momentHoliday=>({date:momentHoliday.format('DD.MM.YYYY'),name:momentHoliday.isHoliday() })
)

////// gives us //////

[ { date: '17.01.2000', name: 'Martin Luther King Jr. Day' },
  { date: '14.02.2000', name: 'Valentine\'s Day' },  { date: '21.02.2000', name: 'Washington\'s Birthday' },
  { date: '17.03.2000', name: 'Saint Patrick\'s Day' },  { date: '21.04.2000', name: 'Good Friday' },
  { date: '23.04.2000', name: 'Easter Sunday' } ]
```